# What methods run after ViewGroup.addView() executed?

Tags: android, android-viewgroup

Trying to handle addView method - calculate some parameters after changes in layout (but before showing whole view), but what methods execute after addView() runned? 
OnLayoutChangeListener and OnMeasure... anything else?

Comment: onMeasure followed by onlayout.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a view as child into another view. You should go like this.

```
public void someMethod() {
View parentView;

View childView = (View)findViewById(R.id.my_view);
parentView.addView(childView);

// Now perform your calculations here. which you want to modify for childView. after that just call the invalidate() method to take changes effect.

parentView.invalidate();
}
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to tell if answer is not as expected.